# How to reach 100% total destruction with the Mighty Eagle in Angry Birds?

Tags: achievements, ios, angry-birds

I recently purchased the Mighty Eagle in Angry Birds for iPhone.  To use him, you toss out a can of sardines and the Eagle swoops down to retrieve it, destroying everything in it's path, including all the pigs.  If the Eagle destroys everything, you get a feather (you're rated on a percentage scale, e.g. 85% destroyed, 93% destroyed, etc.). Get enough feathers and you earn some achievements. I've been able to earn a few feathers, but haven't figured out what has to happen to get to 100%. Everytime I've earned 100%, there are usually some wood/glass/stone pieces leftover.

What criteria does the game use to measure the amount of destruction the Mighty Eagle has wreaked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple way would be to keep trying till you destroy everything.  Note that you can use some of the other birds before using the Eagle!

However, there is a "4-stars" score for each level, invisible to you.  (See: Eagle Score on [this AngryBirdsNest post](http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/2010/12/angry-birds-mighty-eagle-explained/)).  You have to reach that score with the eagle to get 100%.  The percentage of that score you get is the percentage shown to you.  Note that just like with regular scores, *how* the bricks fall affects the points/percentage you get, and not just how much you destroy.

**Spoiler:** Check out this YouTube video for an example of how to get 100%:

Note that [there are some differences](http://www.rovio.com/en/news/blog/148/all-about-the-space-eagle-and-the-danger-zone/) between the Mighty Eagle and the Space Eagle:

> [U]sing a space eagle doesn’t automatically wipe out all the pigs. Instead, you have to pick the perfect spot to fling the can of sardines, and the space eagle will appear in a wormhole of destruction that pops all the pigs around it.
>
> But don’t worry, space eagles travel in flocks -- so if your first try doesn’t do the job, bring on another space eagle! Unlike the Mighty Eagle, there are no time restrictions on use, and you can use several per level.

Comment: I think you're right.  I've earned several eagle feathers since you posted your answer and it definitely feels like it is score based, not number of items based.