# How is the Space Eagle Highscore calculated?

Tags: angry-birds-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reach 100% total destruction with the Mighty Eagle in Angry Birds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14092/how-to-reach-100-total-destruction-with-the-mighty-eagle-in-angry-birds)

Using a Space Eagle, the scoring on a level changes from points to a percentage of a feather. It's unclear to me exactly how the scoring mechanism changes. With the few Space Eagles I've received, I ran 5 tests and got varying results on Level 1-1.

- I destroyed everything: the bird, and the 3 pieces of wood, and received an 88%
- Again, I destroyed everything and received a 91%
- Next, I destroyed all but 1 piece of wood and received an 81%.
- Next, I destroyed everything and received a 92%
- Lastly, I circled the planet one time, then activated the power, and destroyed all but 2 pieces of wood, and received a 79%.

It seems that destroying more things will result in a higher percentage, but when you destroy everything, what is left to reach 100%? How is the percentage calculated, and what exactly is affecting the changes in percentage when destroying all items? Is there a consistent way to achieve 100% on levels?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds exactly like [the way the eagle works in the other games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/14094/6066), relevant portion bolded:

> [T]here is a "4-stars" score for each level, invisible to you. [...] You have to reach that score with the eagle to get 100%. The percentage of that score you get is the percentage shown to you. Note that just like with regular scores, **how the bricks fall affects the points/percentage you get**, and not just how much you destroy.

Note also that you can destroy things with the regular birds first before using the eagle, which can sometimes lead to a better outcome.